# What are the chances of recovering any data from *-flat.vmdk file which didn't finish coping?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vmdk, vmfs, vmdk

Does anybody know if there is a chance of recovering data from a *-flat.vmdk file from (ESXi 6 /VMFS-5) which didn't finish coping? Unfortunately backup is not available.
The image file was thick provisioned and the size of incomplete file is bigger than the content of the image. So what I'm missing is empty space maybe.

Comment: A copy implies that the original file remains intact at it's original location. Copying from where to where? Copying how?

Comment: the file was being copied with cp from one volume to another but the original was deleted before it could finish

Answer (score 1):

Try mounting it on a linux box and see. Something like

```
 kpartx -av <image-flat.vmdk>; mount -o /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/vmdk
```

You may have to force the offset etc but I've had good results doing this in the past.